# React Native Foreground Service: A new timer is created every time the app relaunches

Tags: react-native

What I'm trying to achieve is to create an Android app that fetches a duration value from the backend, and starts a timer that updates the UI every second ( timer value shown as mm:ss ). When the duration value is reached, a local notification is shown to user and the UI changes.

I'm using notifee for local notifications.

Since the app still needs to fire the notification when the app is in the background or killed ( via task list? ), I'm using notifee's foreground service to make the timer run while the app is closed or in the background.

Everything works fine up to here.

When I kill the app by swiping in the task list, the timer ( setInterval ) still lives in the background. ( I'm checking through console )

But the problem begins when I click the notification to bring back the app from the killed state. When the app re-launches a new timer is started ( setInterval ) and two seperate timers run simultaneously. If I kill & relaunch a third timer is added and so on.

Only the latest timer is bound to UI and others just linger in the background.

Solutions I tried:

- Save the old timer id in asyncstorage and clear it when the app relaunches, but that id is not defined in the new scope and can't be cleared with the new instance of the app.
- Save a flag in asyncstorage like "timerStarted" when the first timer starts, and when the app relaunches, check that flag and don't start a new timer. This prevents multiple simultaneous timers, but since the running timer is detached from the UI, it doesn't update the UI and other timer-related functions fail to execute.

I think the main problem is a new instance of the app is created every time I kill & restart by touching the notification.

At this point only two solutions that I think of are:

- BEST: Somehow kill the stale / previous timer. Is it possible to control previous timer from the new instance?
- Prevent getting a new instance of the app and keep the killed instance and bring it back without  mounting components again etc. ( Is this even possible? )

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my AsyncStorage approach was correct, I just missed the correct type for the timer id. Converting to int works like a charm.

So,

- create a timer with setInterval
- save the id to AsyncStorage
- close the app in task manager, but it runs in the background ( so does the timer )
- launch the app again and check for the timer id in AsyncStorage
- Convert the id to int !!! and clear the timer.
- Start  a new timer.